# How to find a directive from a directive using ViewChild/ContentChild?

Tags: angular

I have a component `comp` with a directive `findTarget` aplied to it.

```
<comp findTarget>
</comp>
```

`comp` holds an element with `target` directive:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'comp',
  template: `
    <div target>
      Target
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [Target]
})
```

I want to find `target` directive from inside `findTarget` directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[findTarget]'
})
export class FindTarget {
  @ContentChild(Target) ctarget: Target;
  @ViewChild(Target) vtarget: Target;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log('Content', this.ctarget)
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('View', this.vtarget)
  }
}
```

but I get

```
Content undefined
View undefined
```

Full code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/kc6q445iT1TcLqexqqAg?p=preview

**Update:**
ContentChild seems to work if I move `target` from `comp` element into its template:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3MQj2Dv8tK036EL8GU8f?p=preview
but that not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Directive doesn't have template so you can't get `ViewChild` directly.

You can try to use parent reference like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[target]'
})
export class Target {}

@Directive({
  selector: '[findTarget]'
})
export class FindTarget {
  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => App)) private app: App) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('View', this.app.vComp.vtarget) 
  }
} 

@Component({ 
  selector: 'comp',
  template: `
    <div target>
      Target
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [Target]
}) 
export class Comp {
  @ViewChild(Target) vtarget: Target;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <comp findTarget>
    </comp>
  `,
  directives: [Comp, FindTarget]
})
export class App {
   @ViewChild(Comp) vComp: Comp;
}
```

[**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/S8mGAWeph5VPZ0wAe6Yg?p=preview)

Comment: What about ContentChild?

Comment: `this.app.vComp.vtarget` I can't do that. I don't know path to neither App nor Comp in my real application.